# Why mysql compare "IN" as a like

Tags: mysql, sql-in

I have a table with following data

*Table transactions*

```
trasaction_id
886
456
654_asd
898_ASDF
```

If I use these sentence

```
SELECT trasaction_id from transactions where transaction_id IN (886,654)
```

I expect the result be `886`,

But mysql is returning `886,654_ASDF`

Why is `654_ASDF` returned in that query?

Comment: What is the type of the `trasaction_id` [sic] column?

Comment: `'654_asd'` is coerced to an int.  `SELECT 654 = '654_asd' == 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because `transaction_id` is a string, but your comparison values are numbers.  Hence, `transaction_id` is being converted to a number, using "silent conversion".  That means that errors are not reported.

The conversion is not really using `like`.  It proceeds by converting the leading characters of the string to a number, if they look like a number.  Subsequence characters are ignored.

So, just use the correct types:

```
SELECT trasaction_id 
FROM transactions 
WHERE transaction_id IN ('886', '654');
```